# Error while compiling Web RTC for Android

Tags: android, terminal, command, webrtc, videochat

I am developing app of video chat in Web RTC.

I am going through [documentation](https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/) of Web RTC.

I have followed all steps mentioned for **Getting the Code**

```
export GYP_DEFINES="OS=android"

fetch --nohooks webrtc_android

gclient sync
```

I have all src code of web rtc in my root directory. As per documentation say we have to compile source to use in our application. Here i got error while compiling source using following command.

```
$ gn gen out/Default --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="arm"'



  ERROR at //build/config/android/internal_rules.gni:636:3: Can't load input file.
  import("//third_party/ijar/ijar.gni")
  ^-----------------------------------
Unable to load:
  /Users/c86/webrtc-checkout/src/third_party/ijar/ijar.gni
I also checked in the secondary tree for:
  /Users/c86/webrtc-checkout/src/build/secondary/third_party/ijar/ijar.gni
See //build/config/android/rules.gni:8:1: whence it was imported.
import("//build/config/android/internal_rules.gni")
^-------------------------------------------------
See //webrtc/examples/BUILD.gn:12:3: whence it was imported.
  import("//build/config/android/rules.gni")
  ^----------------------------------------
See //BUILD.gn:13:5: which caused the file to be included.
    "//webrtc/examples",
    ^------------------
```

How can I solve this? Am I going in right direction to develop app of video chat on Web RTC?

Answer (score 2):

Building WebRTC for Android is only supported on Ubuntu(14 / 16).
Currently not supported in macOS.

Comment: i'm using Mac OSx.